# Painting an Image object on a BufferedImage for later use

Tags: java, image, panel, bufferedimage, drawimage

I need some help with painting an Image object upon/inside/on a BufferedImage and then painting that BufferedImage on a JPanel.

I've prepared a small program to illustrate my problem. Just a frame with a panel accompanied by an ImageLoader.

The image is placed in the same folder as the code. The sten Image is painted successfully when just painted, but not when I try painting it with the BufferedImage, which you'll notice if you try to run the program. just create the Test object and the constructor does the rest.

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

static class ImageLoader {
    public static Image loadImage(String name){
        Image img = null;
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ImageLoader.class.getResource(name));
        return img;
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel{

    Image sten;
    BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public Panel(Image sten){
        super();
        this.sten = sten;
        initBF();
    } 

    private void initBF(){
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bf.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(sten, 0,0,this);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(bf, 100,100,null);
        g.drawImage(sten, 0,0,null);
        repaint();
    } 
}


public Test(){
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setEnabled(true);
    this.setBounds(50, 150, 500, 500);
    setVisible(true);

    Image sten = ImageLoader.loadImage("sten.png");;

    Panel panel = new Panel(sten);
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    panel.setSize(500, 500);
    this.add(panel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel.paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage` loads images asychronously so will not be loaded when `paintComponent` is invoked. Use a `MediaTracker` to block until the image has been loaded:

```
public Image loadImage(String name) {
   Image img = null;
   MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(myPanel); // pass the panel from ctor
   img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ImageLoader.class.getResource(name));
   tracker.addImage(img, 0);
   try {
      tracker.waitForID(0);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return img;
}
```

or *far simpler*:

```
img = ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(name)));
```

This will eliminate the need to use `MediaTracker`.

Some notes:

- Don't call `paintComponent` directly, request repaints by invoking `repaint`.
- Don't use `getGraphics` for custom painting - this uses a transient `Graphics` reference.
- When using a custom `Graphics` reference, make sure to call `Graphics#dispose` when finished using the reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the additional tips!

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Reimeus' aswer, notice that `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage()` is non-blocking, it loads images asynchronously, so at the point when you call `g.drawImage(sten, 0,0,this);` `sten` will probably not still actually be loaded (see the doc of the method). See also this (false) [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4298019).

Comment: When I use the same method in other applications I add synchronized to the method declaration. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: No, `synchronized` has little to do with it.